# Laravel 2D Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to send a 2D array in response to a GET Request. The Request is sent via:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","physician/"+physician,true);
```

and it is processed by:

```
public function phyInfo($phyquery){

        $results = DB::table('physician2')->select('Physician_Profile_ID', 'Recipient_City', 'Recipient_State')->where('Physician_Full_Name', $phyquery )->get();
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($results as $result) :
            $data[$count]['name'] = $result->Physician_Full_Name;
            $data[$count]['city'] = $result->Recipient_City;
            $data[$count]['state'] = $result->Recipient_State;
            $count=$count+1;
        endforeach;

        return Response::json(array($data));
    }
```

But in response all I get is the name(which I've already sent in the query), like:
{'John Doe'}.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong over here?

Comment: $data is already an array, why you are using array() method in there?

Comment: I tried using return Response::json($data); but that didn't work so I tried return Response::json(array($data)); . It still didn't work.

Comment: What does $data look like?  var_dump($data).  You don't need make $data an array element as you do in the 2nd to last line.